# Class '...SiteModuleService' not found when used inside scout.php

Tags: modules, composer

I have a custom SiteModule that is used inside scout.php to deliver indexing data to Algolia.
I have followed [CraftQuest's tutorial](https://craftquest.io/courses/algolia-powered-search-in-craft-cms/22271) on creating a custom SiteModule for handling the indicies.

**The setup works when running locally.** But when I run it on my host (Hyperlane), I get the error:
`Class 'modules\sitemodule\services\SiteModuleService' not found`

I reference the SiteModule in scout.php thus:

```php
'indices'       => (new \modules\sitemodule\services\SiteModuleService)->getIndicies()
```

App.php contains:

```php
return [
    '*' => [
        'modules' => [
            'site-module' => [
                'class' => \modules\sitemodule\SiteModule::class,
            ],
        ],
        'bootstrap' => ['site-module'],
    ]
];
```

- Composer version (local/prod): 2.0.12
- PHP version local/prod: 7.3.12/7.3.3

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Worked when I added a `use`-statement to the top of scout.php:

```php
<?php
use modules\sitemodule\services\SitemoduleService as SitemoduleService;
```

And then:

```php
'indices'       => (new SitemoduleService)->getIndicies()
```